# VB using a ADO Recordset inside a vb function, checking for null

Tags: function, vba

I have some weird behavior that has me perplexed. I created a function in vb (Microsoft Word Macro version of VB) which looks like this:

```
Public Function isitnullorempty(newstring As String) As Boolean
    If IsNull(newstring) Or IsEmpty(newstring) Or newstring = "" Then
        isitnullorempty = False
    Else
        isitnullorempty = True
    End If
End Function
```

It seems to work as expected if I create a variable and then set it to null, "", or leaving it empty. I manipulate the variable and then do MSGBOX isitnullorempty(variable) and it echos what I expect. It doesn't behave the same way when I put a recordset inside the function however. I've even tried to make a variable set it to the record set and then test it but that doesn't work either. If I try to invoke the following

```
'ADO query code here (This is an ODBC connection)
DO While (Not oRecordset.EOF)
    MsgBox isitnullorempty(oRecordset.Fields("CustomerTypeRefFullName"))

    oRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
```

This yields the error: Invalid use of Null.

So two fold question.

Is there already a vb function that exists which does what I want?
Why does my code behave this way?

Weirder yet is that if I do the test individually outside of the function, it works.

**Temporary Solution**

It writes more code than it needs to but since I can't seem to call the function with the recordset value I will just individually check each record according to my needs like this:

```
 If IsNull(oRecordset.Fields("CustomerTypeRefFullName").Value) Or IsEmpty(oRecordset.Fields("CustomerTypeRefFullName").Value) Or oRecordset.Fields("CustomerTypeRefFullName").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "potato"
End If
```

Comment: Have you tried being more explicit and using .Fields("CustomerTypeRefFullName").Value ? Right now you're technically passing in a Field object, not its value...

Comment: isitnullorempty = (Len(newstring & "") = 0)

Comment: That was a good guess but that didn't do it. -isitnullorempty(oRecordset.Fields("CustomerTypeRefFullName").Value) -did not do the trick but it was a good guess. I assumed if - MsgBox oRecordset.Fields("CustomerTypeRefFullName") - worked I didn't have to explicitly call it's value. I am afraid I don't understand your second comment??

Comment: That's a suggestion to replace the body of your isitnullorempty function.

Comment: haha, so that will either be 1 or 0 depending on input?! haha, wow nice. :)

Comment: Offtopic... what about replace the `oRecordset.Fields("CustomerTypeRefFullName").Value` by a variant with this value? Then, you'd be doing your test against the variant instead of the recordset value.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean assigning another variable to oRecordset...Value? Like Dim somevar as string; somestring = rcdset...Value? That seems to give me the same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is if you want to pass a null to a function's parameter that parameter needs to be set as variant. 
     Public Function isitnullorempty(newstring As Variant) As Boolean

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me you have the logic wrong:

If IsNull(newstring) Or IsEmpty(newstring) Or newstring = "" 
Then
    isitnullorempty = *False*
Else
     isitnullorempty = *True*
End If

Shouldn't it be

If IsNull(newstring) Or IsEmpty(newstring) Or newstring = "" 
Then

isitnullorempty = **TRUE**

Else

isitnullorempty = **FALSE**

End If

Comment: hehe yeah I noticed that I ask the question but answer in the negative. Regardless of if I return true or false though shouldn't it run regardless? Thanks for pointing it out, i'll change it.

Comment: I'd go with Tim's first option, explicitly getting the value out of the field for your test.  If that still throws the error, try casting that value to a string.

Comment: 1 Dim testvar As String 2 testvar = oRecordset.Fields("CustomerTypeRefFullName").Value 3 MsgBox isitnullorempty(testvar) I still got the error. This is really strange...

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but what data type is the field CustomerTypeRefFullName?

Comment: vb isn't my usual language, according to this function: http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/04/get-variable-type.html it is Null(No valid Data)

Comment: SO I guess I am trying to pass a null value to the function. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: My reason for asking the datatype of the field, is in case it was a bit value, or a decimal field value, for example, would be to do the casting of the value to a string before passing it to your function, which requires a string.